# Upload file using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to upload a file using selenium webdriver. Below is the html code:

```
<a class="add-doc" onclick="javascript:clickVideo();" href="#">
<input id="file_count" type="hidden" value="0" name="file_count"/>
<input id="profile_id" type="hidden" value="2" name="profile_id"/>

I have tried uploading the file using :

driver.findelement(By.xpath("Xpath of the element")).sendKeys("path to file");
```

but this is not working for me. Can anyone please help me on this. UI is something like, There is only one button on the page on which i have to click. This will open up a pop up to browse file from the machine.

Comment: Could you please look for an input element with `type="file"` and post it's HTML representation (the element is probably hidden)?

Comment: maybe you need call the js mathod "clickVideo()" -> Look that the input is inside on it. If you are trying to upload inside while the site uses jcrop, you will need do all it using js / jquery

Comment: Can you help me with a sample jquery which I can use to upload file??

Comment: There is no input element with type="file".